# Find which WorkItems are Code Reviews using the TFS API

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015

Given a list of WorkItems, I would like to find the instances that correspond to a Code Review using the TFS 2015 API in C#.

While I can see from the text of the Description whether a WorkItem is a Code Review, I would prefer avoid parsing that string and rely on something more robust (eg: [WorkItem.Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem.type(v=vs.120).aspx))...

How would you do that (the Type value seems quite cryptic to me)?

Comment: WorkItem.Type.Name is the simple way to determine the work item type. I would like to know what the instance like that you want?

Comment: OK, I already went for the WorkItem.Type.Name solution... I was just unsure whether checking for a type name was robust enough (I was think I should compare with an existing type instance from the store), but it seems that `workitem.Type.Name == "Code Review Request"` is good enough, right?

Comment: You can define a enum (https://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/enum-with-string-values-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the method below to get a workitem's type. But you need to provide the workitem id.

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

        Uri collectionUri = (args.Length < 1) ?
            new Uri("http://servername:8080/tfs/MyCollection") : new Uri(args[0]);

        // Connect to the server and the store. 
        TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection =
           new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri);

         WorkItemStore workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        string queryString = "Select [State], [Title],[Description] From WorkItems Where [Work Item Type] = 'Code Review Request' or [Work Item Type] = 'Code Review Response'";

        // Create and run the query.
        Query query = new Query(workItemStore, queryString);
        WorkItemCollection witCollection = query.RunQuery();

        foreach (WorkItem workItem in witCollection)
        {
            workItem.Open();
            Console.WriteLine(workItem.Fields["Title"].Value.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: Given a list of WorkItems, I used this code to filter the ones that are Code Reviews:  `workItems.Where(x => x.Type.Name == "Code Review Request")`. But is there really nothing more robust that a string comparison? Or is that type name set in stone in TFS?

Comment: I have a list of work items (from my project, yes), and I simply want to filter the ones that are code reviews. I guess your test will work fine (so does mine), but I was looking for something more robust than a test on the type name. Are you saying that this test is robust enough and that what I am after is an overkill?

Comment: @GyumFox Using a workitem query to find those workitems you want.

Comment: That would do. My question was more about the correctness of relying on a string comparison for identifying work items based on the name of the type, but I guess this is an accepted practice when working with TFS.

Comment: @GyumFox Using a work item query is more better that a string comparison. Workitem query is designed to filter workitems by some conditions in TFS.  To learn more about workitem query: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/using-queries.